# How can I prevent VSCode devcontainers from setting GIT_EDITOR

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

When using Visual Studio Code (vscode) devcontainers the extension automatically sets vscode as the git editor. It does this by setting the `GIT_EDITOR` env var.

To prove it, I ran:

```bash
docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm bin/bash -c 'echo ${GIT_EDITOR}'
```

which didn't return anything. To prove that it would return a value if it were set run

```bash
docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm bin/bash -c 'echo ${HOSTNAME}'
```

which *will* return a command (proving that my `docker run` command is correct).

[image: screenshot of running the aforementioned commands]

However, if I use that image for my devcontainer in **.devcontainer/devcontainer.json**:

```json
{
    "name": "Debian",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm"
}
```

and then inside the devcontainer run:

```bash
echo $GIT_EDITOR
```

it returns:

> code --wait

[image: screenshot of running echo $GIT_EDITOR inside the devcontainer]

Clearly the devcontainers extension is setting `GIT_EDITOR`. However I don't want to use vscode to edit git messages, I prefer to use the command-line. How can I stop it from doing so? Obviously I can simply

```bash
unset GIT_EDITOR
```

but its rather tedious to do that over and over again. I wonder if there's a setting that I can set in devcontainer.json that prevents `GIT_EDITOR` from getting set?

Answer (score 0):

This solves it:

```json
{
    "name": "Debian",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm",
    "containerEnv": {
      "GIT_EDITOR": "vi"
    }
}
```

However I don't really want to specify anything, I'd rather each user of the devcontainer set it to whatever they want without mandating what the default should be. Hence why I'd just like to configure the devcontainer to simply not set `GIT_EDITOR`.

Comment: what if you put `null` in the place where you've put `"vi"`?